# Mongodb transactions fail to roll back changes when exception triggered

Tags: mongodb, transactions, pymongo, atomic

Ive set up a replicaset on a server with a primary, secondary and arbiter instance of mongodb. Firewall exceptions passed, all three instances are able to communicate with each other. Im testing out multi collection consecutive writes to documents using transactions. For the sake of testing, i added an exception but my successful writes dont get rolled back by mongodb. What am I missing out? Im using mongodb 4.2 on my server and my pymongo version is 4.4
My connection string has been updated and Im able to connect to my primary, rs.status() indicates all 3 instances are up and running.

Code below:

```
with client.start_session() as sessi1:
    sessi1.start_transaction()
    try:
        rew3A=db.Coll1.update_one({Query1},{'$set':{Update_Params_1})
        1/0
        rew2A=db.New92.update_one({Query2},{'$set':{Update_Params_2})
    except Exception as er1:
        print(f'Exception is {er1}')
        sessi1.abort_transaction()
    else:
        sessi1.commit_transaction()
```

I would basically like the rew3A update to be rolled back on account of the exception triggered by dividing by zero.

Comment: Would the [transaction model shown in the `pymongo` docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/client_session.html#transactions) be preferable?  Or alternatively add `session=sessi1` to your collection command parameters?

Comment: you should provide a session into each operation where you expect transaction effect

Comment: Both of you, thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed! I had to pass sessi1 to the update_one queries, and that is it. Off to the races. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

@dododo and @rickhg12hs, thank you so much! You are right, I wasnt providing the session as an input to the update queries. Doing so worked!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You should use comments to reply to answers.